# Heroku deployment ignores my files and folders

Tags: node.js, github, heroku

I've been working in a node-js app for heroku for the last 9 months. It was deployed for the first time like 7 months ago and since then, it has been working fine.
All this time, i've done many deployments **using github** to this app for adding new functionalities or correcting bugs and i have never found any problem.
But yesterday, in another normal deployment where i had just added a few logs, the app crashed, with the message "**module xxxx.js could not be found**".
In fact, since yesterday, **neither that file nor any of the files i've developed** are being deployed to heroku.
And when i say "**i've developped**" i mean that heroku is deploying everything in the branch (the whole node_modules folder and all its content) but my folder (which is also inside node_modules)
I rolled back the app to the last deployment before yesterday and it started to work properly again, but i can't deploy anything now, please help!
I've tried to change the repository to a new one and add new folders or files to node_modules, checked .gitignore file (which is empty)... but nothing seems to work

Comment: just reset your working commit

Comment: I've tried to reset my commit, create a new branch from the last commit that worked fine. I've even tried to create a new repository and deploy it and nothing seems to work. In fact, in I can see all the elements I'd like to deploy in the repository, but when I deploy it to heroku, my elements inside node_modules are ignored. Is there some kind of list of elements from node_modules folder that are being deployed??